# Наползание элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

У меня есть некоторый workzone с #can, который выглядит вот так: (серый элемент - это отдельный див)

[image]

при нажатии на кнопку я методом append добавляю в #can еще один серый див, после добавления все выглядит так:
[image]
так вот вопрос: как сделать, чтобы серый элемент не пристыковывался к первому, а был поверх него?

Comment: А z-index добавляете к новому элементу?

Comment: Добавлял, это ничего не изменило.

Comment: fiddle сделайте уже наконец.

Comment: Сделайте код в [jsfiddle][1] телепатов здесь нет.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить двум элементам абсолютное позиционирование (`position: absolute`) с одинаковыми значениями `top` и `left`.
2. Установить относительное позиционирование (`position: relative`) с отрицательными значениями отступа (`margin`).